# How do you get Eclipse to auto-suggest methods?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just deleted Eclipse and the Android SDK completely, and reinstalled them together from the Android SDK bundle. (I did this because a lot of bloat had built up over time and I couldn't get SDK Manager to recognize new versions of ADT.)

Eclipse used to pop up with a list of all available methods of a class if I typed the name of the class and then a dot, and would start filtering the list down as I continued to type. This feature is not working since I reinstalled. How can I turn it on?

I already installed API 17's sources and documentation in SDK Manager.

Comment: See if you have content assist enabled. Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist. Look at all the preferences in this category, something might be unchecked that should be checked.

Comment: That was it--thanks for getting me on the right track.

Comment: It's making me wait two days before I can accept it.

Comment: Haha, alright then, no interfering with your answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following boxes needed to be checked in the Java -> Editor-> Content Assist -> Advanced section of the Preferences:

- Java Non-Type Proposals
- Java Proposals
- Java Type Proposals