# Eclipse - Why .class isn't auto suggested?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-assist

I'm using Eclipse 2018-09 (but same issue also in other versions)

When I write code using `.class`, for example for logger:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyServiceImpl.class);
```

`.class` is never auto suggested by Eclipse even by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

I tried to check all [Java auto suggest methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714913/how-do-you-get-eclipse-to-auto-suggest-methods) in code assist prefernces

Why valid `.class` isn't suggested by Eclipse? can it be enabled?

[image]

No `.class` in auto suggestion:

[image]

Comment: I is. When I type `String.`, it shows up in the suggestion menu. A matter of versions or modified settings, perhaps?

Comment: @ernest_k I don't think it's version related, but I don't have this option shown/suggested, but also I tried changing all code assistant properties

Comment: Try Ctrl + Space ? tbh I've never used Ctrl + Enter, is that the default mapping?

Comment: @JornVernee still not working (same )

Comment: Please lets have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986750/ctrl-space-not-working-for-content-assist-on-eclipse)

Comment: @SudhirOjha I tried both cases of all checked and only Java proposals checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue,

It was because I added Type Filter of `java.lang.Object` (to [avoid suggesting Object methods](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502843))

When I remove/uncheck it `.class` is added to suggestion